# How to evaluate the performance of a predictor on an unlabelled dataset? What is an appropriate test set size and how to sample it?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, statistical-significance, unsupervised-learning, record-linkage

I am working on a project with goal to deduplicate a customer database. We don't have any annotations (no training/test set with the ground truth values). 
We implemented multiple unsupervised algorithms following the record linkage pipeline (http://recordlinkage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/about.html ) but we don't know how we can assess the performance of these algorithms.

What would be the size of a statistically significant dataset of pairs of records and how should we select it in order to correctly assess the results?
Secondly, how could we select the minimal training set if we wanted to use supervised learning?

Comment: You cannot say that a method deduplicates a dataset if you have no way of knowing which records are false positives (not actually a duplicate). I believe this is what you are calling "annotations". Statistical significance does not factor into a problem that has no hypothesis.

Comment: We do want to annotate a subset in order to test the performance. The goal is to find the minimal size which would provide generalisable results. At the other extreme, labelling the entire input defeats the purpose of building a classifier.